# указатель на примере маленькой функции

Tags: c

```
void inc(int *p) { (*p)++; }                     

void main()
{
   int       a;                                
   inc(&a);
}
```

немного в ступоре, функция получает как бы разыменованный указатель, то есть значение, но передаем мы в нее не значение а адрес. Маленький такой вопрос, как собственно это работает

Comment: Функция `inc` принимает аргумент `p` типа `int*`, т.е. указатель на целое. Так что все ОК.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov здесь и `C` тоже нет.

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил ваш вопрос, то, пожалуйста, отметьте этот ответ "галочкой" рядом со "стрелочками" (которые "вверх"/"вниз"), чтобы вопрос не висел в списке не отвеченных.

Answer (score 5):

Вы передаете адрес переменной `a`, которую создаете на стеке в функции `main`, в функцию `inc`, которая в качестве параметра принимает указатель на переменную типа `int` (т.е. `int*`, так как результатом взятия адреса переменной (`&a`) является указатель на область памяти, где она находится), затем же вы разыменовываете указатель посредством `*p` и применяете к нему постикрементный `operator ++` посредством `(*p)++`. В итоге, инкрементится сама переменная `a` из функции `main`.

Не путайте объявление/определение переменной, как указателя на `int` через `int* p` и её разыменование (т.е. обращение к объекту, на который указывает указатель) посредством `*p` в отличном от объявления/определения месте.

Answer (score 1):

Функция получает указатель, а разыменование этого указателя происходит здесь: `*p`.

Comment: Т.е. первая звездочка квалифицирует аргумент как указатель, а вторая его разыменовывает